# Wordpress CSS and PHP not being applied

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to host a wordpress blog off of an Amazon EC2 server instance and it was working fine, however when I associated it a new IP address all of the CSS for wordpress went away and i cant access any of the backend php scripts and get a 404 when i add the /wp-admin to try to access the backend navigation.

Does anyone know how to resove these issues and tell wordpress to use this new IP address?

Comment: did update **wp-config** file?

Answer (score 0):

During the initial installation, did you host the blog such as
http://192.xyz.xy.123/ ?

If yes, take an sql dump of database, search and replace old ip with the new ip.
Restore dump. And everything will be restored.